# How would I write a query which checks whether a subquery list of dates is between a range of dates from the main query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query which takes joins multiple tables. The main table contains a start_date and end_date field which is operating correctly against the record. However, using a CASE WHEN statement appears to only be returning the first result of the date from the second table. What I need to do is:

- For each record returned by the main query with a date range, I need to check if that candidate in another table has made themselves available during that date.

I've tried using a case when statement, but it returns only the first date of the table I've joined prior.

```
SELECT N.start_date as 'Shift Start', N.end_date as 'Shift End',
   CASE WHEN (CA.start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date AND CA.available = 1)
        THEN "Was available on this date"
        ELSE "Was not available on this date"
   END AS 'Available On Shift Date',
   CASE WHEN (CA.start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date AND CA.available = 1) 
        THEN CONCAT(CA.start_date,' -> ', CA.end_date)
        ELSE "N/A"
   END AS 'Marked Availability',
   CASE WHEN R.status = 1 THEN "Accepted"
        WHEN R.status = 0 THEN "Unanswered"
        WHEN R.status = 2 THEN "Declined"
        ELSE "Request status unrecognised"
   END AS 'Request Status',
   CASE WHEN (CA.available = 1 AND CA.start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date )
        THEN "Available"
        WHEN (CA.available = 0 AND CA.start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date )
        THEN "Busy"
        ELSE "Unknown availability status"
   END AS 'Candidate Available/Busy'
FROM x.candidates as C,
   x.candidates_availability as CA,
   x.requests as R,
   x.requirements as N
WHERE CA.candidate_id = C.id
   AND R.candidate_id = C.id
   AND R.requirement_id = N.id
   AND C.id = 1444 # test value
GROUP BY N.id;
```

This statement:
`WHEN (CA.available = 0 AND CA.start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date ) THEN "Busy"`
is failing due to the fact that CA.start_date is returning the first result in its respective table, rather than checking the list of values and comparing each one against the date range N.start_date and N.end_date

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? (Your query is invalid standard SQL)

Comment: It would help to see input, incorrect output, and desired output.

Comment: Side note -- it's best practice to use explicit joins.

Comment: Also use a valid `GROUP BY`.  That statement should not run.

Answer (score 0):

> CA.start_date is returning the first result in its respective table, rather than checking the list of values and comparing each one against the date range

If you want to compare every row in CA, CASE... WHEN doesn't do that. You probably want something like (boolean, you can add the `CASE` around it):

```
EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM CA WHERE candidate_id = C.id AND available=1 AND ... )
```

and remove CA from the join list.

If you want the last status in the period then you can use (returns int, you can add case around it):

```
(
    SELECT 
        available 
    FROM 
        CA 
    WHERE
        candidate_id = C.id AND
        start_date between N.start_date and N.end_date 
    ORDER BY 
        start_date DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

In either case, you need a subquery, `CASE ... WHEN` does not do filtering or aggregation of any kind. And remove the CA join.